# Make Actionbar transparent in Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using android studio 3.0 and want to make actionbar transparent with activity's background.I just read all the questions about it but that doesen't work for me.help me guys.

minSdkVersion 20

targetSdkVersion 26

here is my style.xml code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
</style>
```

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJSHD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme to make your  `Actionbar` transparent

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@mipmap/ic_left_back</item>

</style>
```

Comment: @RaviGohel  **`not proper transparent`** means

Comment: it display white color on action bar

Comment: can u share screen shot because its working fine in my device @RaviGohel

Comment: give me email address i will send you photo of my output of the app

Comment: still same output

Comment: is anyone there ??